# How to include the entire length of arrays?

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

Below I created this filter method to only display what's found within the fullDetails array.

I apologize if this question is unclear and if I'm using the wrong terminology.

Right now it can work if I input each element individual (eg. fullDetails[0]). But the array has 4 elements. How can I write it so that it includes the entire length of array? (ie. [0] [1] [2] [3])?

```
let modItemList = this.props.items.filter(
        (item) => {
            return item.fullDetails[0].toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchItems.toLowerCase()) !== -1;
        }
    );
```

Comment: Can you show us a data sample and an expected result ?

Comment: The question is not clear .Please show the input the array and also expected output

Comment: Ok. 1 moment @Zenoo

Comment: Also . What do you want to return? A string that has all values comma separated?

Comment: Your filter is supposed to filter out all elements where *none of `fullDetails` contains `searchItems`*?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your filter is supposed to keep items whose `fullDetails` array contains `this.state.searchItems` (case-insensitive), you're looking for the [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) method of arrays:

```
let lc = this.state.searchItems.toLowerCase(); // Do this once
let modItemList = this.props.items.filter(
    (item) => item.fullDetails.some(e => e.toLowerCase().indexOf(lc) !== -1)
);
```

`some` calls its callback for each entry in the array, stopping and returning `true` if the callback returns a truthy value (if it never does, `some` returns `false`).

Instead of `indexOf`, you could also use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) (ES2015, like `let` and arrow functions):

```
let lc = this.state.searchItems.toLowerCase(); // Do this once
let modItemList = this.props.items.filter(
    (item) => item.fullDetails.some(e => e.toLowerCase().includes(lc))
);
```

Comment: @Reuben: but be aware that the Internet Explorer does not support `.includes()`.

Comment: @cars10m - Or arrow functions, which Reuben is already using. So presumably transpiling or targeting only modern environments.

Comment: :D :D - very true!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `every` to check if every element matches.

```
let modItemList = this.props.items.filter(
    (item) => {
        return item.fullDetails.every(fullDetail => fullDetail.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.state.searchItems.toLowerCase()) !== -1);
    }
);
```

However, the plural in `searchItems` indicates that this could be an array either - so maybe you need to flip/enhance the logic here.