# Writing if/else statements with 3 conditions with a promise mixed in

Tags: javascript, if-statement, react-native, es6-promise

So I have this conditional statement with 2 conditions, whereby

```
let modItemList = this.props.items

    if (this.state.searchItemName) {   // condition1
        modItemList = (
            this.props.items.filter(
                (item) => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(lcName) !== -1    // For name
            )
        );
    } else if (this.state.searchItemAddress) {    //condition2
        modItemList = (
            this.props.items.filter(
                (item) => item.fullAddress.some(e => e.toLowerCase().indexOf(lcAddress) !== -1)      // For Address
            )
        );
    }
```

This is where it's a little tricky to explain.

Now I want to add a 3rd condition, which happens only if both condition1 and condition2 are met, AND the outcome is that of executing code from condition1 and condition2.

How would I go about expressing that?

Comment: I'm afraid you've made things too abstract. :-) What is `filter` in this code?

Comment: Indeed, too abstract.  Please review how to create a [mcve] - we can't guess what you're after very effectively, so some code that _actually_ demonstrates the issue would be super useful.

Comment: Ahh right apologies. I'll try rewrite with a better example of code

Comment: Hi again @T.J.Crowder aha. This is a little embarrassing. I'm actually building up on an answer of mine you helped yesterday. 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52198682/how-to-include-the-entire-length-of-arrays

Comment: What's the asynchronous aspect? In that question, you're just filtering an array...

Comment: I've updated the code example. Sorry it took so long. I'm not using my computer at the moment so I had to recall and write the exact problem I am facing

Comment: How you derive your condition1 and condition2 is important,Is it async then you need promises, otherwise u can simply derive

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes, you're right. However, now I'm trying to filter an array twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no asynchronous action here, so no need to track an async action with a promise.

Probably the simplest thing is to filter the filtered list:

```
let modItemList = this.props.items;
if (this.state.searchItemName) {
    modItemList = modItemList.filter(item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(lcName));
}
if (this.state.searchItemAddress) {
    modItemList = modItemList.filter(item => item.fullAddress.some(e => e.toLowerCase().includes(lcAddress)));
}
```

Or filter once and check for `searchItemName` and `searchItemAddress` within the callback:

```
let modItemList = this.props.items.filter(item =>
    (!this.state.searchItemName    || item.name.toLowerCase().includes(lcName)) &&
    (!this.state.searchItemAddress || item.fullAddress.some(e => e.toLowerCase().includes(lcAddress));
```

Even if the list is in the hundreds of thousands of entries, neither of those is going to be slow enough to worry about.

Or if it really bothers you do do that double-filtering or re-checking, build a filter function:

```
let modItemList;
let filterFunc = null;
if (this.state.searchItemName && this.state.searchItemAddress) {
    filterFunc = item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(lcName) && item.fullAddress.some(e => e.toLowerCase().includes(lcAddress));
} else if (this.state.searchItemName) {
    filterFunc = item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(lcName);
} else if (this.state.searchItemAddress) {
    filterFunc = item => item.fullAddress.some(e => e.toLowerCase().includes(lcAddress));
}
modItemList = filterFunc ? this.props.items.filter(filterFunc) : this.props.items;
```

That involves repeating yourself a bit, though, leaving open the possibility that you'll update one address filter but not the other. You can aggregate the filter functions:

```
let nameCheck    = item => item.name.toLowerCase().includes(lcName);
let addressCheck = item => item.fullAddress.some(e => e.toLowerCase().includes(lcAddress));
let modItemList;
if (this.state.searchItemName && this.state.searchItemAddress) {
    modItemList = this.props.items.filter(item => nameCheck(item) && addressCheck(item));
} else if (this.state.searchItemName) {
    modItemList = this.props.items.filter(nameCheck);
} else if (this.state.searchItemAddress) {
    modItemList = this.props.items.filter(addressCheck(item);
}
```

If there were more than two, we might look at putting them in an array and doing

```
modItemList = this.props.items.filter(item => arrayOfFunctions.every(f => f(item)));
```

So...lots of options. :-)

---

I've used `includes(x)` rather than `indexOf(x) !== -1` above. I find it clearer.

Comment: I would buy you a beer if you were around. Thanks again for the help :-)  Clearly I was overthinking things while trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

I think you just want to use two separate `if` conditions where both may run, not `if`/`else if`:

```
let modItemList = this.props.items;

if (this.state.searchItemName) {   // condition1
    modItemList = modItemList.filter(item =>
        item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(lcName) !== -1    // For name
    );
}

if (this.state.searchItemAddress) {    //condition2
    modItemList = modItemList.filter(item =>
        item.fullAddress.some(e => e.toLowerCase().indexOf(lcAddress) !== -1)      // For Address
    );
}
```

Nothing is asynchronous here or involves promises. If it did, I would recommend to just place an `await` in the respective location.

Comment: How would this help with my problem?

Comment: @Reuben It does what you asked for: if both conditions are met, then both filters are applied. The result is stored in `modItemList`.

Comment: Yes you're right. Sorry if my tone was a little harsh.

Answer (score 0):

You would still need to wait with the action till promise is resolved and finished. So you would check the conditions inside of promise callback and then make adequate actions. Until you have resolved promise, you can display some "loading" information.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this solution You want?

```
if (condition1 & condition2) {
   something = this.props.something.filter(1)).then(this.props.something.filter(2)
} else if (condition1) {
   something = this.props.something.filter(1)
} else if (condition2) {
   something = this.props.something.filter(2)
}
```

Comment: .then is a construct used with Promises. .filter will return an array and will fail.